# trigger throwing too may soql error on EmailMessage object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on one trigger on EmailMessage object.
I have Application object, whenever I am receiving an incoming email,I want to update CC field to owner email of application object.

I worked on below trigger but its throwing too many soql error, I am unable to understand where I did mistake

Can anyone help me out in this issue.

```
public class PopulateCConEmail {
public static void EmailMessage(){
    List<EmailMessage> updateEmailMessage = new List<EmailMessage>();
    List<EmailMessage> allEmails = [select Id,RelatedToId,CcAddress,Incoming from EmailMessage where Incoming =true limit 100];
    set<Id> relatedId = new set<Id>();
    for(EmailMessage email : allEmails){
        if(email.RelatedToId != null){
            relatedId.add(email.RelatedToId);
        }
    }
    Map<Id,Application__c> appMap = new Map<Id,Application__c>([select Id,Name, OwnerId,Owner_Email__c from Application__c where Id in: relatedId]);
    for(EmailMessage e : allEmails){
        if(appmap.containsKey(e.RelatedToId)){
            e.CcAddress = appMap.get(e.RelatedToId).Owner_Email__c;
        }
        updateEmailMessage.add(e);
    }
    upsert updateEmailMessage;

}

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger PopulateCC on EmailMessage (after insert, after Update) {

PopulateCConEmail.EmailMessage();
 }
```

Comment: I am able to solve this issue, I should use before insert and before update in trigger and need to remove the update functionality from class

Comment: A different problem: you are not passing Trigger.new to the Apex class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your logic to only work on the records contained in the trigger transaction. The trigger can pass the new and old records.

```
trigger PopulateCC on EmailMessage (after insert, after Update) {
    PopulateCConEmail.EmailMessage(trigger.oldMap,trigger.newMap);
}
```

The class SOQL can then filter by Map.

```
public class PopulateCConEmail {
    public static void EmailMessage(Map<Id, EmailMessage> oldEmailRecords, Map<Id, EmailMessage> newEmailRecords) {
        ....
        Map<Id,Application__c> appMap = new Map<Id,Application__c>([select Id,Name, OwnerId,Owner_Email__c from Application__c where Id in: newEmailRecords.keySet()]);
        ....
    }
}
```